# What is the connection between matter in the universe and the baryon number not being conserved?

Tags: cosmology, conservation-laws, standard-model, baryons

Towards the end of "Quarks, the Stuff of Matter", the author discusses the implications of the proton is not stable and ultimately decays.  He states, that if the proton decays, then the baryon number is not conserved and that would explain why there is matter in the universe and not pure energy from matter / antimatter annihilations.

I do not see the connection between the 2....
There is a distinct lack of explanation in the book... granted it was written in the 80's... But how, does the lack of conservation of the baryon number explain why matter is dominate?

Comment: Do readers know you are discussing Harald F's book?

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, proton decay just is a implication that the conservation of baryon number is not really constant and that it can change. So currently, the Standard Model predicts that baryons are perfectly stable in terms of the conservation of baryons(Of course individual baryons can be created or destroyed through pair production but total baryon number is conserved). So if we detect proton decay now, it can mean that baryon number violation can potentially occur at any point in the universe's history, present, and also the future.

So from there we can extrapolate that if there is a slight preference for matter to antimatter(if there had been the reverse we would have a universe full of antimatter), then it means that we live in a universe full of matter because the processes that happened near the Big Bang, allowed for antimatter to swap into matter and there was a reduced chance of the reverse.

The other argument could be that potentially antiprotons just decay faster than protons which could also explain why we have more protons, and that the extreme conditions of the big bang speeds up decay and that protons just aren't affected by that and so don't decay as quickly and take upwards of 10^32 years.

But the final conclusion is that we are left with a matter-antimatter imbalance with more matter than antimatter, and then after all the antimatter is destroyed, there is just matter.

So to summarize, baryon assymetry just means that there is a possibility that it could have happened in the past, and given the current CPT violation and potentially given that other types of matter-antimatter preference violations exist, it could mean that more matter could have existed earlier on.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] if the proton decays, then the baryon number is not conserved and that would explain why there is matter in the universe [...]

If there exists a single process with $\Delta B\ne0$, i.e. baryon number is not conserved, then other processes could have the same property (energy to matter, for example), with symmetry reasonings clarifying which ones do and which ones do not hold.
To our present knowledge, symmetry prohibits *any* baryon nonconservation, so if the proton decays it means that also the other processes need to be rethought.

The main effect of baryon number conservation being exact is (or at least should be) the fact that the total baryon number is conserved, and for every baryon created in a process an antibaryon is also created, thus if one starts with zero baryons and zero antibaryons (as physicists think the Universe did), the number should not change.

If $B_{t_0}=0$, and $\Delta B=0 \quad\forall$ processes, then $B_{t}=0\forall t$, which is not what we see with $t=t_\text{today}$.

If $B_{t_0}=0$, and $\exists$ some process with $\Delta B\ne0$, then $B_{t}\ne0$ in general, which is what we see with $t=t_\text{today}$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's clarify what we mean by baryon number conservation: In the Standard Model of particle physics, baryon number is a conserved quantity. This means the number of baryons (particles like protons and neutrons) minus the number of antibaryons (their antiparticles) should remain constant in any process. However, if proton decay occurs, it would imply that the baryon number is not an absolutely conserved quantity, since a proton (a baryon with baryon number +1) would decay into other particles that are not baryons (like positrons and pions), effectively reducing the baryon number of the universe.

Now, let's consider the early universe. According to cosmological observations and theoretical models, the universe began in a hot, dense state in which matter and antimatter were created in nearly equal amounts. However, we observe that the universe today is composed almost entirely of matter, with very little antimatter. This asymmetry is known as baryon asymmetry.

For the universe to evolve from an equal mixture of matter and antimatter to a state dominated by matter, some processes must have occurred that favored the production or survival of matter over antimatter. This requires a violation of certain symmetries, specifically CP symmetry (the combination of charge conjugation symmetry and parity symmetry). Andrei Sakharov laid out conditions for generating the baryon asymmetry of the universe, one of which is the violation of baryon number conservation.

The connection between proton decay and matter dominance can be understood as follows:

If proton decay exists, then a more general theory that allows for baryon-number violation is in order. This is one of [Sakharov's conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryogenesis#GUT_Baryogenesis_under_Sakharov_conditions), the other two being CP-Violation and Interaction outside the thermal equilibrium.

If the laws of physics allow for baryon number violation, as would be implied by proton decay, then in the early universe, when conditions were extreme, these processes could have led to a small excess of baryons over antibaryons. Once the universe cooled down and the processes that could annihilate matter and antimatter became less frequent, the slight excess of baryons would remain, leading to a universe filled with matter.

I hope this roughly gives a sense as to why baryon number violation could give rise to matter domination.